# How to add search box in document

Tags: search

I didn't have a search box in my document :
[image: noSearch]

How can I add one?

Comment: might help you: http://brainlitter.com/2012/12/31/display-search-box-nowhere-to-be-found-in-a-sharepoint-2013-web-part/

Comment: Didn't work... I've set to default and check "Display search box" but don't show me the search box...